# Passing XML resource to XMLReader

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax, xmlreader

I am trying to pass a `.xml` file from my `res` folder to an `XMLReader` in order to parse it to an object:

```
private void parseXML() {
    String parsedData = "";
       try {
           Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Start");
           /** Handling XML */
           SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
           XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

           QuestionXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new QuestionXMLHandler();
           xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
           InputSource inStream = new InputSource();
           Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Parse1");

           inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(getResources().getXml(R.xml.questions).toString()));
           Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Parse2");

           xr.parse(inStream);
           Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Parse3");

           ArrayList<QuestionMaster> questionList = myXMLHandler.getQuestionsList();
           for(int i=0;i<questionList.size();i++){
                QuestionMaster question = questionList.get(i);
                parsedData = parsedData + "----->\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "Queston No: " + question.getQuestionNo() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "QuestionText: " + question.getQuestionText() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "CorrectAnswer: " + question.getQuestionText() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "WrongAnswer1: " + question.getQuestionText() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "WrongAnswer2: " + question.getQuestionText() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "WrongAnswer3: " + question.getQuestionText() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "Answered: " + question.isAnswered() + "\n";
                parsedData = parsedData + "QuestionText: " + question.isAnsweredCorrectly() + "\n";
            }
            Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Done");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity",e );
        }
        xmlOutput.setText(parsedData);
    }
}
```

I am sure that it is the line:

```
inStream.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(getResources().getXml(R.xml.questions).toString()));
```

Could someone guide me to pass this *`.xml` file to the `XMLReader`*.

*edit*:

Changed it to:

```
InputSource inStream = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
xr.parse(inStream);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help however when i use your changes i get : The method parse(InputSource) in the type XMLReader is not applicable for the arguments (InputStream)

Answer (score 3):

`getXml()` returns an implementation of the `XmlPullParser`, and so it is already set to be [parsed using that engine](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). Change your existing code to use `XmlPullParser` instead of SAX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the file either in raw or asset folder to use SAX parser and then using context read that file from there

Android - Read file from Assets
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/02/android-read-file-from-assets.html